# Trouble with inheritance in C++

Tags: c++, inheritance

I'm having trouble getting the std list class to call the proper function on a class. It keeps calling the base class' function only. Here's what's happening:

I have a state class with the following update function which is declared virtual in the header:

State.h update function:

```
virtual void update(float elapsed);
```

State.cpp update function:

```
void State::update(float elapsed){

};
```

and a class that inherits from it called TestState:

```
class TestState::public State{
        virtual void update(float elapsed){
             if (GLOBALENGINE->getInput() -> getKeyPress(DIK_Q)
                PostQuitMessage(0);
        };

};
```

I call the addState function to add a new state to the linked list and make it the current state as follows:

```
GLOBALENGINE->addState(new TestState,true);
```

The addState function looks like this:

```
void GameEngine::addState(State *state, bool change){
    states->push_back(*state); //add the test state into the states list

    // some irrelevant code

    currentState = &(states->back());//currentState is a pointer to a State
    // So we make it point to the newly added state.


}
```

Then the run() function is called every frame and inside of it is the following code:

```
currentState->update(elapsed)// This should call the update function in TestState!
```

I thought that this line should call the update function in TestState but instead it calls only the function in the State class (ie: it does nothing).

Can someone explain how I can get the functionality I'm looking for?

Thanks

Comment: How is the `states` list declared?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should store in the list a pointer (or a smart pointer) to your object, not an object directly, or you lose polymorphism.  In

```
states->push_back(*state);
```

you are instructing `push_back` to construct a copy of `state` and add the copy in `states`.  The copy is of type `State`, not `TestState`, and thus does not behave the same way.

This behaviour is called object *slicing*; see for example [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/274626/what-is-the-slicing-problem-in-c).